# LoadRunner VuGen

Tags: c, json, нагрузочное-тестирование

есть с LR такая ситуация: после записи скрипта и его генерации LR предлагает открыть каждый JSON файл, который приходит в ответах на запросы, записанные в скрипте. После последующих запусков этого уже записанного скрипта подобных ситуаций не возникает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно отключить это или что с этим делать? Установлен LoadRunner 2021, Windows 11, скрипт записывался через Firefox.